# Test coverage with Karma, browserify and Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, code-coverage, karma-runner, browserify, istanbul

I'm having troubles to add test code coverage, I'm using Karma and files added to Karma are already bundled with browserify, so in `karma.conf.coffee` it looks like that:

```
files: [
   { pattern:'bin/public/client/app.js', served:yes: included:yes }
   { pattern:'src/lib/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', served:yes: included:yes }
   { pattern:'bin/tests.js', served:yes: included:no }
]
```

*And that works for running the test, but not coverage*

I'm using `karma-coverage` npm package, and this:

```
preprocessors: 'bin/public/client/app.js':['coverage']

reporters: ['progress','coverage']
```

Actually does create coverage stat files, but those are completely wrong, because it reddens parts that browserify brought from node_modules (because I don't have tests to cover those)

Ideally I have to gather source maps that browserify generates, and run coverage against those, but browserify embeds source maps into .js files. Using `karma-sourcemap-loader` lets me see original coffeescript files of tests, when debugging (for some reason it works only in ChromeCanary, nevertheless it works)

I tried to do `preprocessors: 'src/client/**/*.coffee':['coverage']`, but that yields no stats at all saying 'No data to display'

Do you have any ideas?

**upd:**

I've figured by running `browserify-istanbul` transform right after `coffeeify` and that gave me nice diagram like this: [image]

Now, I need somehow to remove app.js from it, because really it doesn't matter and really confuses

**upd:**

Oh, instead of javascript I have to supply coffee files:

```
preprocessors : {
    'bin/tests.js': ['sourcemap']
    'src/client/**/*.coffee': ['coverage']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I answered my own question. Also it seems there's a bug in current version of `karma-coverage` - it throws an error when `coverageReporter.type` is `html` (which is by default html). I'm glad I've figured it out. It's always nice to see how much code covered by tests

Comment: @RobertLevy I'm using Gulp. I'm still working on generalizing things, planning maybe to wrap things into a Yeoman generator, so I could reuse same stack as a bootstrap point in my other projects. And of course making it open-source is a part of the plan. Although in its current state project is still too young and has tons of things that need to be polished

Comment: I'd also like to see your config, even in an unpolished state.

Comment: Actually, I think the html report is broken because Istanbul doesn't support reporting on Coffeescript. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/QZW3ClF_1r4, https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/43, https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/56. The text report works because it just reports percentages per file and doesn't force the issue by annotating lines like the html report does.